# Implement a similar articles feature in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a rails app which have a job model and a company model. job is belongs_to :company and company has_many: jobs

the job has : job_title, country and company_id
the company has: company_name and company_industry
I want for each job to show the related job based in the similarity of the country company_industry and company_id, can somebody guide me to implement this feature?

Update

this is my job model

```
class Job < ActiveRecord::Base

  validates_presence_of :company_name, :job_title, :experience, :contrat, :job_description, :profile_recherche, :job_contact



    belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :user



    searchable do
        text :job_title, boost: 4
        text :profile_recherche
    end


      def company_name
        company.try(:name)
      end

      def company_name=(name)
         self.company = Company.find_or_create_by(name: name) if name.present?
      end



    extend FriendlyId
    friendly_id :job_title, use: :slugged



end
```

this is my job controller

```
class JobsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_job, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]


  def index
    @jobs = Job.paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 6)
  end


  def search

    @jobs = Sunspot.search(Job) do
      keywords params[:query]
      fulltext params[:query]
      paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 1)
    end.results

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { render :action => "index" }
    end

  end



  def show
  end


  def new
    @job = Job.new
  end


  def edit
    @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id])
  end


  def create
    @job = Job.new(job_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @job.save
        format.html { redirect_to @job}
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
      end
    end
  end

def update
  respond_to do |format|
    if @job.update(job_params)
      format.html { redirect_to @job }
    else
      format.html { render action: 'edit' }
    end
  end
end


  def destroy
    @job.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to jobs_url }
    end
  end


  private

    def set_job
      @job = Job.find_by_slug(params[:id])
    end


    def job_params
      params.require(:job).permit(:job_title, :experience, :contrat, :job_description, :profile_recherche, :job_contact, :company_id, :company_name)
    end
end
```

Comment: I suggest you put the relevant code from the model, view, controller you have so far. Could you explain in more detail what you mean by "similarity"? Also, to be clear do you really want all three items to be "similar", because that would seem to resolve to just *company_id*, which is then just following that one relation?

Comment: I want at last one of the three items to be similar and i mean by similar "related jobs" like the feature that we find in blog "related posts"

Comment: it might be possible that job belongs to different company also....right ?

Comment: could you please show your code like how you find your job on controller or model ?

Comment: I have added one answer below....but i do not exactly your code...but i think that code should work. Please check

Comment: Do you want to fetch the related jobs on your index method ??

Comment: i want to implement something like this but i don't use tag http://dev.mensfeld.pl/category/ruby/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50984/discussion-between-lalitharyani-and-user3304070)

Answer (score 0):

Try this
You have particular job and then get the related jobs

```
 job = Job.where(id: params[:job_id]).first
 related_jobs = Job.where("id != '#{job.id}'").where("company_id = '#{job.company.id}' OR country = '#{job.country}' ")
```

it will gives you all the related jobs that belongs to current company that you have or that is having the same country that your current job.

Comment: You could/should remove original job from the related list (exclude by id in the query might be easiest)